# error C2512: 'Building' : no appropriate default constructor available

Tags: constructor, building

```
class Building{
private:
int floor;
public:
Building(int s) { floor = s;}
};

int Main(){
Building twin, star;
Building BlueHouse(5), JangMi(14);
}
```

I made this code, and when I build the code 'error C2512: 'Building' : no appropriate default constructor available'  comes up. It's been only a few weeks since I'v started learning c++ , and I'm having quite a hard time ;< Help me out, c++ masters!

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
Building twin, star;
```

it means to create `twin` and `star` using the default constructor, since you didn't provide any initializers.  But you have not defined a default constructor, so this is an error.

To fix this, add a default constructor, e.g. within `class Building`'s `public` section:

```
Building(): floor(0) {}
```

Note that I used the syntax for initializing variables in the constructor, this is actually the same as `Building() { floor = 0; }` when `floor` is just an `int`, but if you had other member variables which were of class type, then there is a difference.

Alternatively you could add a default value to your existing constructor:

```
Building(int s = 0): floor(s) {}
```